Difference between incandescence and fluorescence
In the contest of blackbody radiation, from a molecular point of view, what is the mechanism which allows the conversion from heat to electromagnetic radiation?
I think in the IR range is easier to imagine with the help of some classical knowledge: temperature is correlated to kinetic energy of molecules, which rotates and vibrates in agreement with quantization, so they emit EM radiation of this frequency coming back to the lower energy states.
I need details on it to a deeper understanding.
And what about the production of visibile light, for example, from a hot body (incandescence)? Is heat also able to induce electronic transition? How?
This way incandescence becomes similar to fluorescence and there is something that doesn't convince me.
What is the difference between incandescence and fluorescence?
There are a lot of things here (black body, incandescence, energy conservation, quantization) but I'm searching for answers and some hint to rationalize the confusion I've got on this matter.
Also references (article, books) with qualitative and/or mathematical approaches are well accepted.
